# DynaTree: How do you expand all children ( downstream node levels) from a active node?

Tags: dynatree, jquery-dynatree

I've got a 4 level tree and would like to expand all of its children (and children's children) when a level 2 node is activated.  I can determine the current activate node level with:

```
if(node.getLevel() == 2)...
```

I thought something like:

```
if(node.getLevel() == 2) node.expand(true)
```

But that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement the `onActivate` event handler to expand all nodes recursively.

```
onActivate(node){
    if(node.getLevel() == 2){
        node.visit(function(n){
            n.expand(true);
        });
    }
}
```